# SAS - How to read correctly the DateTime Stamp in the data as shown below?

Tags: sas

How to read correctly the DateTime Stamp in the data as shown below?

```
data mydata;
  infile cards truncover expandtabs;
  input DateTimeStamp :Date18. ASN $CWC $ TS $ Mno X Y;
cards;
28SEP2016:09:03:51.000 20 US02062 R 1 304 -38044
;
run;
```

The above code does not read the datetime as in the following **wanted** format:

```
28SEP2016:09:03:51.000
```

But actually following come out as result, which **I do not want**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are reading it in as Date18 (a date informat).  You need to use a date-time informat, such as DateTime18.  You should probably also format it as a date-time, to make it human readable when printed.

```
data mydata;
  infile cards truncover expandtabs;
  input DateTimeStamp :DateTime18. ASN $CWC $ TS $ Mno X Y;
  format DateTimeStamp datetime.;
cards;
28SEP2016:09:03:51.000 20 US02062 R 1 304 -38044
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
data mydata;
  infile cards truncover expandtabs;
  input DateTimeStamp :anydtdtm32. ASN $CWC $ TS $ Mno X Y;
  format DateTimeStamp datetime.;
cards;
28SEP2016:09:03:51.000 20 US02062 R 1 304 -38044
;
run;
```

It should help you with any date time stamp type you have.